# Am I using Fusion Drive?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, macbook, fusion-drive

I just installed a Fusion Drive on my late 2011 Macbook Pro 17".

But I'm not sure now if i'm using Fusion Drive now...

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Screenshot1]
<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>
[image: Screenshot1]
<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>

Can anyone tell me if I'm using Fusion Drive or not?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. What drive did you add? Did you just add a second hard drive, or did you [create a logical volume group too](http://www.macworld.com/article/2014011/how-to-make-your-own-fusion-drive.html)? What's the output of `diskutil list`?

Comment: Yes I did also create a logical volume group. diskutil list says: http://www.restyles.de/Other/fushiondrive/bild4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be fine. Your Macintosh HD volume is a logical volume created through `CoreStorage`, and it's spanning across your two physical hard drives.

You can check `diskutil list` and `diskutil coreStorage list`. These should show your two drives belonging to the same logical volume.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks you! I just checked out diskutil coreStorage list. Its says: http://www.restyles.de/Other/fushiondrive/bild5.png

So it should be fine?

Comment: Yep, looks good to me!